# How do I parse some data from a String, and store it to a variable

Tags: javascript, regex

So let's say I want to handle a URL, and I need an algorithm to get a data from my link.

My url has this shape: `myapp://auth/userId/token`

For example: `myapp://auth/123/444444`

How can I store 123 in a variable called `userId`, and 444444 in a variable called `token`?

Comment: You can achieve this using from Api Call (Get Request). If you are using javascript then use Fetch api or url must return something as response

Comment: In which language would you like the answer? Javascript or Dart?

Comment: Hi @GulshanAggarwal, thank you so much for your response, I have received the answer.

Comment: Hi @Mattia, thank you so much for your response, I have received the answer.

Comment: So this question has nothing to do with the `dart` language

Comment: @Mattia I'm using dart, I tagged javascript to get another answer since they are very similar. I was thinking to use regex earlier, but the answers have shown different approaches. My bad.

Comment: IMO regex is still the way to go. This is how most modern routers extract slugs from URLs. It also allows for more complex matching. In your case the matching is simple enough so they can be extracted purely from their position between slashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split it by `/` and use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the last 2 items.

```js
const [userId, token] = "myapp://auth/123/444444".split('/').slice(3);
console.log(`userId=${userId}, token=${token}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use destructuring and Array.split().

```js
let url="myapp://auth/123/444444"
const [channel, userid, token] = url.split("//")[1].split("/")
console.log(userid, token)
```

Answer (score 1):

Split it by character and work with array's indexes

Comment: This may be a correct answer, but as it's stated, it's more of a comment. Consider increasing the quality of your answers by adding code to demonstrate your idea, and if possible make it a snippet so the OP (and others) can see it work in action.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use a RegEx and capture groups:

```
const myUrl = "myapp://auth/123/444444";
const regexpUrl =  /^myapp:\/\/auth\/(?<userId>\w+)\/(?<token>\w+)/;
```

Usage:

```
const match = regexpUrl.exec(myUrl);
const extracted = { userId: match.groups.userId, token: match.groups.token };
```

You could also restrict the slugs to only digits with this pattern:

`^myapp:\/\/auth\/(?<userId>\d+)\/(?<token>\d+)`